How can I modify my EF Core query to include an array conversion
Problem Statement
I am using Entity Framework (EF) Core and PostgreSQL. In my target table, there is a JSONB column that might contain a version number. My goal is to sort the query by this version number, but the version needs to be sorted as integers.
Target PostgreSQL query:
ORDER BY 
    string_to_array("Metadata"->>'version', '.')::int[]

Current EF Core query:
query.OrderBy(_ => EF.Functions.StringToArray(_.UserMetadata!.RootElement.GetProperty("version").GetString()!, "."))

This EF Core query generates the following PostgreSQL query:
ORDER BY 
    string_to_array("Metadata"->>'version', '.')

However, the conversion to ::int[] is missing, which is crucial for sorting by integer values.
Question
How can I modify my EF Core query to include the ::int[] conversion so that the generated PostgreSQL query includes the important part for integer sorting?

@Charlieface, It generates this code (order by string_to_array("Metadata"->>'version', '.')::integer[])

Hmm I got CAST(... AS integer[]) although they come to the same thing. Which versions is that?

EF core 8, PostgreSQL 14.2.

You can just use a normal C# cast. Because of C# typing rules, you need to cast to object first.
query.OrderBy(x => (int[]) (object) EF.Functions.StringToArray(x.UserMetadata!.RootElement.GetProperty("version").GetString()!, "."))

Ideally you would store your version number as an int[] array in the database in the first place.
Eg, instead of {"Version":"1.2.3"} you would have {"Version":[1,2,3]}. Then you can just do something like
query.OrderBy(x => (int[]) (object) x.UserMetadata!.RootElement.GetProperty("version").GetString()!)


what is the amount of boxing and unboxing that will happen in this code?

None, because of the way SQL translation works. The only question is will there be extra casts in the SQL, checking using ToQueryString shows it does a normal CAST(... AS integer[])

out of curiosity I posted the question is ChatGPT and it got me another very long answer... then I asked again about your answer then it said that it won't work... but you got the correct answer... this is the link to conversation if you are interested.
https://chatgpt.com/share/7dc28be4-3fae-4837-a6e3-937a829d0f16

@sabsab it's not odd at all. Random text generators don't understand anything. They generate words based on the statistics of the words you posted and the words they already generated

I think you need a property that marked [NotMapped]
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string VersionStr { get; set; }
    
    [NotMapped]
    public int[] VersionNums => VersionStr.Split(".").Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
}

